# I have a problem meaking shared_ptr of a member function

Tags: c++, methods, shared-ptr, functor, std-function

I am trying to make a shared_ptr of a method of a class (the actual working function of functor). I want that pointer to be passed into a function caller. However, I cannot manage to do that. the code that I have is the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using Func_t = typename std::function<void(int)>;

void function_caller(std::shared_ptr<Func_t> func, int the_other_num) {
  (*func.get())(the_other_num);
}

class increment{
public:
  // constructor
  increment(int n) : num{n} {}
  // destructor
  virtual ~increment() =default;
  //increment function:
  void operator()(int other_num) {
    cout << "the num should be : floor[" << num <<
        " * " << num + 1 << " / "<< num-1 << "]"<< std::endl;
    this->num = num * (num + 1) / (num - 1);
    cout << "the num is :" << num  << std::endl;
    cout << "the sum of num and the other number is :"
         << num + other_num << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  int num;
};

int main()
{
  increment incr(2);
  auto function_ptr{std::make_shared<Func_t>(&incr())};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    function_caller(function_ptr, i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and my compilation fails with

```cpp
cd ~/tmp/ && g++ member_function_caller.cc && ./a.out
member_function_caller.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
member_function_caller.cc:35:52: error: no match for call to ‘(increment) ()’
   35 |   auto function_ptr{std::make_shared<Func_t>(&incr())};
      |                                                    ^
member_function_caller.cc:19:8: note: candidate: ‘void increment::operator()(int)’
   19 |   void operator()(int other_num) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~
member_function_caller.cc:19:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

and when I change the code to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using Func_t = typename std::function<void(int)>;

void function_caller(std::shared_ptr<Func_t> func, int the_other_num) {
  (*func.get())(the_other_num);
}

class increment{
public:
  // constructor
  increment(int n) : num{n} {}
  // destructor
  virtual ~increment() =default;
  //increment function:
  void operator()(int other_num) {
    cout << "the num should be : floor[" << num <<
        " * " << num + 1 << " / "<< num-1 << "]"<< std::endl;
    this->num = num * (num + 1) / (num - 1);
    cout << "the num is :" << num  << std::endl;
    cout << "the sum of num and the other number is :"
         << num + other_num << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  int num;
};

int main()
{
  increment incr(2);
  auto function_ptr{std::make_shared<Func_t>(&incr(int other_num))};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    function_caller(function_ptr, i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

it fails with

```cpp
cd ~/tmp/ && g++ member_function_caller.cc && ./a.out
member_function_caller.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
member_function_caller.cc:35:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
   35 |   auto function_ptr{std::make_shared<Func_t>(&incr(int other_num))};
      |                                                    ^~~
```

I will really appreciate if someone helps me fixing it.

Additionally, I need to keep the parameter of the function caller as a `std::function` to be able to keep my API that I need for different part of my codes.

Comment: I am actually looking for possible answers rather than changing the ```function_caller```

Comment: Forget about `shared_ptr` for the time being and first learn about pointers to members, and the differences between member functions and free functions.

Comment: I have another function that takes std::shared_ptr to an std::func object (not presented in this minimal example). I want to make sure how can I use a functor instead so I can have the freedom to work with functors as well. @molbdnilo

Comment: The simplest version is probably `std::make_shared<Func_t>([&incr](int i) {incr(i);})`

Answer (score 0):

this version worked as expected:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using Func_t = typename std::function<void(int)>;

void function_caller(int the_other_num, std::shared_ptr<Func_t> func = nullptr) {
  (*func.get())(the_other_num);
}

class increment{
public:
  // constructor
  increment(int n) : num{n} {}
  // destructor
  virtual ~increment() =default;
  //increment function:
  void operator()(int other_num) {
    cout << "the num should be : floor[" << num <<
        " * " << num + 1 << " / "<< num-1 << "]"<< std::endl;
    this->num = num * (num + 1) / (num - 1);
    cout << "the num is :" << num  << std::endl;
    cout << "the sum of num and the other number is :"
         << num + other_num << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  int num;
};

int main()
{
  increment incr(2);
  auto function_ptr{std::make_shared<Func_t>([&incr](int i) {incr(i);})};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    function_caller(i, function_ptr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and the oputput is :

```cpp
the num should be : floor[2 * 3 / 1]
the num is :6
the sum of num and the other number is :6
the num should be : floor[6 * 7 / 5]
the num is :8
the sum of num and the other number is :9
the num should be : floor[8 * 9 / 7]
the num is :10
the sum of num and the other number is :12
the num should be : floor[10 * 11 / 9]
the num is :12
the sum of num and the other number is :15
the num should be : floor[12 * 13 / 11]
the num is :14
the sum of num and the other number is :18
```